# Zend Framework 2, Zend_Mail: how to send email with both html and text parts?

Tags: zend-framework2

```
$html = new MimePart($email->getBodyHtml());
$html->type = 'text/html';
    ...
$text = new MimePart($email->getBodyText());
$text->type = 'text/plain';
    ...
$mimeParts = array($html, $text);
    ...
$body->setParts($mimeParts);
```

This works fine, but the email I am getting contains both html and text parts - and I mean they are both shown.

Gmail shows HTML first, and then right there it shows the plain text part. Obviously, I would like only HTML part to be shown, with the text portion only used when HTML is not available in email client.

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 3):

[Rob Allen's DevNotes](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/sending-an-html-with-text-alternative-email-with-zendmail/)

Simple... when you know how!

Comment: Thank you!! That `multipart/alternative` content type header was my problem!

Comment: to write it down here - you have to change the `content-type` header of the mail to `multipart/alternative` like this: `$message->getHeaders()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative');`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions only `http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html`. No `setParts` method.